# Multivariable calculus del notation question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I've been asked to prove that $\frac{1}{2}\nabla(F\cdot F)=F\times(\nabla \times F)+(F\cdot\nabla)F$ where $F$ is the vector field $\langle P(x,y,z),Q(x,y,z),R(x,y,z) \rangle$ and $\nabla=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\rangle$, but I keep disproving it! Please can someone help me with this. (here are my workings so far):[image]

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I am pretty sure your expression for $\nabla \vec F$ is the culprit.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Do you mean my expression for $\nabla \times F$ as that would make more sense? Having said that, I've checked it and I still can't see my error. Can you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

It is a consequence of the [general rue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Product_rules):
$$
\nabla(\vec u \cdot \vec v)=\vec u \times (\nabla \times \vec v)+\vec v \times (\nabla \times \vec u)+(\vec u \cdot \nabla)\vec v + (\vec v \cdot \nabla)\vec u
$$
for $\vec u= \vec v$

---

You have a mistake in the calculus of $(\vec F \cdot \nabla)\vec F$.

Note that $ \vec F \cdot \nabla$ is a ''scalar'' operator:
$$
\vec F \cdot \nabla=P\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+Q\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+R\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
$$
So, when you multiply it by $\vec F$ you have to multiply all the components by this scalar:

$$
(\vec F \cdot \nabla)\vec F= \left(PP_x+QP_y+RP_z\,,\,PQ_x+Qq_y+RQ_z\,,\,PR_x+QR_y+RR_z   \right)
$$

Correct this and you can find the result.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't come across that rule before but I need to be able to prove the original formula so I can't just state the rule. Can you help me spot the error in my workings as I need to be able to prove the case?

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful. And the general rule is obtained in the same way....  :)

Comment: Thanks, I've found my mistake now, I thought that the components of F and the partials were commutative but obviously they're not.